# [__NSCFString fira_UTF32Length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: firebase

This error is basically related to FirebaseAnalytics Framework. It means your framework can't be loaded or it can't be mapped, basically it happens in release mode. As in my case if i ran my app in debug mode then it works fine but when i run it into release this error shows.

Answer (score 2):

If you are NOT using cocoa pods (did a manual install, like i do), this will happen if you do not add "-ObjC" to the other linker flags.

Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: This is required if you're using SPM as well

Answer (score 1):

I resolve this issue by force loading the FirebaseAnalytics framework like this.

Steps

1. First go to your yourtarget-release.xcconfig file
2. Inside OTHER_LDFLAGS you will see -framework "FirebaseAnalytics"
3. Replace this  -framework "FirebaseAnalytics" with  -force_load "${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics"

Hope this works. It worked in my case.
Thanks.